# Getting Incorrect Letter spacing in flutter web on S22 galaxy (Device Specific Issue)

Tags: flutter

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTR6z.jpg)

Need Help..

I have created the website and deployed when i open my website on the S22 galaxy getting this letter spacing. Anyone know whats the issue ??

I have searched all the way to find the issue but didnt get any clue for this.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Text("${reportHeader.replaceAll(' ', '\n')}",
                  style: secondryHeadingTextStyle.copyWith(
                    color: ProjectColors.pickledBluewood,
                  )),

Comment: you're replacing all spaces with newlines? That seems a bit weird

Comment: Yeah because the text I am getting from the server has spaces so  I need do that